# Install iOS apps using adhoc without plugging the iOS Device on Mac computers

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am currently working on a private iOS app, and was asked to distribute it to only a handful of people without publishing to app store. I know about ad hoc and already created provisioning profile and all the requirement, archived and sent to the iOS device. My first try using ad hoc, sent to iPhone using airdrop, the app automatically installed on the device, all worked great, but all of that while plugging the iPhone in to mac computer that I used for developing the app.

My question is can we do that without plugging it in? I recreates the step with the same phone and on another phone without plugging it in and the apps can't be installed. Or is there difference in steps when plugged in or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install an ad-hoc package to a remote device, you will need to put the IPA file on a web server and also upload the Manifest file.
However, If you don't have a handy server, there are many free services that you can use for that. To mention a few: TestFairy, Diawi.